# Problem with RLE program. (Run-Length Encoding)

Tags: java

How can I make the test work? I don't encounter the error in my code. Java is new to me and I am just learning it. I know that the issue is related to the array, but I don't know how to fix it.

Error of decompress:

> "array lengths differed, expected.length=2 actual.length=5; arrays
> first differed at element [2]; "

Error of compress:

> "array lengths differed, expected.length=3 actual.length=2; arrays
> first differed at element [0]; "

The code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class RLE {
    public static void compress(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        int currentByte = is.read();
        int count = 1;

        while (currentByte != -1) {
            int nextByte = is.read();

            if (nextByte == currentByte && count < 255) {
                count++;
            } else {
                os.write((byte) count);
                os.write((byte) currentByte);
                count = 1;
            }

            currentByte = nextByte;
        }

        os.flush();
        is.close(); 
        os.close(); 
    }

    public static void decompress(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        int currentByte = is.read();

        while (currentByte != -1) {
            int count = currentByte;
            int value = is.read();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                bytes[i] = (byte) value;
            }

            os.write(bytes);
            currentByte = is.read();
        }

        os.flush();
        is.close(); 
        os.close(); 
    }
}
```

The test:

```
import java.io.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class RLETest {

    private void test1(byte[] expected, byte[] input) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        RLE.compress(new ByteArrayInputStream(input), bos);
        assertArrayEquals(expected, bos.toByteArray());
    }

    private void test2(byte[] expected, byte[] input) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        RLE.decompress(new ByteArrayInputStream(input), bos);
        assertArrayEquals(expected, bos.toByteArray());
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void compress() throws Exception {
        test1(new byte[]{1,1,4}, new byte[]{1,1,1,1,1,1});
        test1(new byte[]{1,1,0}, new byte[]{1,1});
        test1(new byte[]{1,2,3}, new byte[]{1,2,3});
        test1(new byte[]{1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0}, new byte[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3});
        test1(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4}, new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4});
        test1(new byte[]{1,2,3,3,0}, new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 3});

        byte[]ar;

        ar = new byte[260];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            ar[i] = 100;
        }

        test1(new byte[]{100,100,(byte) 255, 100, 100, 1}, ar);

        ar = new byte[550];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            ar[i] = 100;
        }

        test1(new byte[]{100,100,(byte) 255, 100, 100, (byte) 255, 100, 100, 34}, ar);
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void decompress() throws Exception {
        test2(new byte[]{5,5}, new byte[]{5,5,0});
        test2(new byte[]{1,2,3}, new byte[]{1,2,3});
        test2(new byte[]{1,2,2,3}, new byte[]{1,2,2,0,3});
        test2(new byte[]{1,2,3,3,3,3}, new byte[]{1,2,3,3,2});
        test2(new byte[]{5}, new byte[]{5});
        test2(new byte[]{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4}, new byte[]{1,1,0,2,2,0,3,3,0,4,4,0});

        byte[]ar;

        ar = new byte[202];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            ar[i] = 55;
        }

        test2(ar, new byte[]{55,55,(byte)200});

        ar = new byte[259];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            ar[i] = 55;
        }

        test2(ar, new byte[]{55,55,(byte)255, 55, 55, 0});
    }

}
```

Comment: In Java, a `byte` is signed, so it's range is from -128 to 127.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, a `byte` value is signed, so its range is from -128 to 127.
As opposed to a range of 0 to 255.

There are two approaches you can take.  I'll demonstrate both.

As a solution, you can reduce your check value, on line 13, of `count < 255` to 127.
For added persistence, you can use `Byte.MAX_VALUE`.

```java
if (nextByte == currentByte && count < 127) {
    count++;
} else {
    os.write((byte) count);
    os.write((byte) currentByte);
    count = 1;
}
```

Or, you can bit-mask your `count` value in the `decompression` method.

```java
count = currentByte & 0xff;
```

This will return positive values for negative `byte` values.
For example.

```java
-1 & 0xff == 255
```

Additionally, as a recommendation, you can reduce both your `compress` and `decompress` methods.

Place the `compress` contents within a try-finally block.
That way, you can close your streams in the event of an `IOException` occurring.
And, increase the scope of `nextByte`, by bringing its declaration outside of the `while` loop.

```java
public static void compress(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    try {
        int currentByte = is.read();
        int nextByte;
        int count = 1;
        while (currentByte != -1) {
            nextByte = is.read();
            if (nextByte == currentByte && count < 255)
                count++;
            else {
                os.write((byte) count);
                os.write((byte) currentByte);
                count = 1;
            }
            currentByte = nextByte;
        }
    } finally {
        os.flush();
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

As for the `decompress` method, same situation, place the contents within a try-finally block.
Your `currentByte` assignment can be placed within the `while` condition statement.
And, you can utilize the `Arrays.fill` method to populate the `bytes` array.

```java
public static void decompress(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    try {
        int currentByte;
        int count, value;
        byte[] bytes;
        while ((currentByte = is.read()) != -1) {
            count = currentByte & 0xff;
            value = is.read();
            bytes = new byte[count];
            Arrays.fill(bytes, (byte) value);
            os.write(bytes);
        }
    } finally {
        os.flush();
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

As an added measure, just to demonstrate what's happening when assigning a value greater than 127 to a `byte`.
Consider the following, we'll start at 125 and increment by 1, 4 times, to get to 129.

```java
byte value;
String binary;
for (int count = 1; count < 5; count++) {
    value = (byte) (125 + count);
    System.out.printf("+%d, ", count);
    System.out.printf("value= %4d, ", value);
    binary = "%8s".formatted(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
    binary = binary.substring(binary.length() - 8);
    System.out.printf("%s%n", binary);
}
```

```
+1, value=  126,  1111110
+2, value=  127,  1111111
+3, value= -128, 10000000
+4, value= -127, 10000001
```

Comment: The problem was with the 255. Now the code works perfect, thx a lot for the tips i appreciate it so much. I'll take notes to avoid repeating this error.